# Frequency of sequences in many files

Tags: python, python-2.7, biopython

Suppose that you have 50 files (in the same folder), and each one contains the character ">" at the beginning of your search. Like the examples:

```
File1.txt
>organism1
>organism2
>organism3
>organism4
>organism5

File2.txt
>organism3
>organism4
>organism5
>organism6
```

My intention is to count the frequency of each organism in each file and generate a table. 
At the moment I count each one file-by-file to generate the table:

```
Table 1.
          Frequency
organism1  1
organism2  1
organism3  2
organism4  2
organism5  2
organism6  1
```

Until now, I can list all file in the folder but can't open them to make what I want.

```
    import sys
    from Bio import SeqIO
    import glob, os

    os.chdir(sys.argv[1])

    file_list = []

    for file in glob.glob("*.faa"):
            if file not in file_list:
                    file_list.append(file) # until here, perfect

for f in file_list:
        infile = open(f, 'r')
        fasta = SeqIO.parse(infile, 'fasta')
        seq = fasta.description  #.split("|")[2]
        print seq
```

The problem is when I try to open the files in file_list.

```
<generator object parse at 0x7f76867c7a00>
<generator object parse at 0x7f76867c7a50>
<generator object parse at 0x7f76867c7a00>
<generator object parse at 0x7f76867c7a50>
```

Comment: `print seq` --> `print(list(seq))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `SeqIO.parse()` as if it were `SeqIO.read()` which won't work.  `SeqIO.parse()` returns a generator since it produces multiple results from the file:

```
import sys
import glob
import os
from Bio import SeqIO

os.chdir(sys.argv[1])

file_list = []

for file in glob.glob("*.faa"):
    if file not in file_list:
        file_list.append(file)

for file_name in file_list:
    for fasta in SeqIO.parse(file_name, 'fasta'):
        description = fasta.description
        print(description)
```

This works in my environment, Python 3.6.0; Biopython 1.69.  In my environment, your code generates the error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'description'
```

instead of producing any output.  I see you're running Python 2.7 but which Biopython?

Why are you filtering duplicates from the result of your `glob()`?